# Populating text boxes on a webpage from a SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, sql

I ran into a problem I hope you can help me with.  I am new to C#, ASP.NET, and SQL, so please bear with me.  I created a table in my DB that contains info about dogs.  I created a webpage with a dropdownlist and several textboxes.  The ddl is populated with the "name" field from the table (that part is working).  What I am trying to is allow the user to select a name from the ddl and then have the textboxes automatically fill with the corresponding info from the selected record.  Every time I try, I get the error: `"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."`

Here is my code for the event handler:

```
protected void ddlDog_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dogs"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM dog WHERE name=@name";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        txtName.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
        txtBreed.Text = reader["breed"].ToString();
        txtAge.Text = reader["age"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = reader["city"].ToString();
        /*if ((bool)reader["pure"] == true)
        {
            cbxPure.Checked = true;
        }*/
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the commented out part, I am also having trouble with getting a bit field in the table to update a checkbox on the webpage.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Melissa, please step through this in the debugger and let me know what line throws the error. This particular error message is a little misleading - it doesn't mean what people think it means. Also check your column names - remove the * from your query and list the column names, then when you read those columns, the names are CASE-SENSITIVE in your C# code, so make sure your casing matches the query (which doesn't have to match the table def because SQL is case-insensitive). Never use the * in code queries - it's a shortcut you should only use in immediate mode.

Comment: BTW, if there are zero rows, HasRows might still be true, and Read() will return false but not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing the assignments in the braces, prior check if there's a row to read

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while(reader.Read()){
        txtName.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
        txtBreed.Text = reader["breed"].ToString();
        txtAge.Text = reader["age"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = reader["city"].ToString();
        }
}
else{
//Empty datareader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
        txtName.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
        txtBreed.Text = reader["breed"].ToString();
        txtAge.Text = reader["age"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = reader["city"].ToString();
        /*if ((bool)reader["pure"] == true)
        {
            cbxPure.Checked = true;
        }*/
}
```

If you are expecting more than 1 result than you can use `while (reader.Read())` instead.

Comment: I tried using the while loop- it still doesn't work, but now I get no error.